# How can I send email to admin for approval or deny, When new user register in website using django?

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am creating a website that allows the user to get direct communication with other member but the new user needs to get approval to login website. Now I want to send an email to admin with new user's bio and approve or deny the link.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use Signals (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) to get the new user object after it has been saved, and send links via email (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/) that will approve or disapprove the user.